# Why does my NetSuite Script fail with a RCRD_DSNT_EXIST error

Tags: javascript, scripting, netsuite

I'm a newbie with NetSuite, so please be gentle.

I have a simple script the aim of which is to delete all the quotes returned from a particular search.

Here it is:

```
function executeSavedSearch()
{
    var searchresults = nlapiSearchRecord('estimate', 1234, null, null);
    for (var i = 0; searchresults != null && i < searchresults.length; i++) 
    {
        var searchresult = searchresults[i];
        nlapiDeleteRecord(searchresults[i].getRecordType(), searchresults[i].getId());
    }
}
```

That's it. But every time I run it it fails and the execution log shows RCRD_DSNT_EXIST, with the details of "That record does not exist."

I've confirmed that the search ID (1234 in the above) is correct any number of times. The search returns a number of records, so it's not that there's no result for the script to work on.

Any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share the Saved Search filters and columns? There might be chance that Main Line/Tax Line/Shipping Line is not set. This causes multiple lines to be shown in Saved Search for a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var estimateSearch = nlapiSearchRecord("estimate", null,
        [
            // add or remove filters as per your need.
            ["formulanumeric: {internalid}", "between", "200", "300"],
            "AND",
            ["mainline", "is", "T"] // In order to avoid duplicate records in result, do not remove this filter 
        ],
        [
            new nlobjSearchColumn("internalid") // Result column
        ]
    );
    var quoteId;
    for (var i = 0; estimateSearch != null && i < estimateSearch.length; i++) {
        quoteId = estimateSearch[i].getValue('internalid');
        nlapiLogExecution("Debug", "Quote ID: " + quoteId, " Index: " + i);
        // nlapiDeleteRecord('Estimate', quoteId); // Verify the Execution Logs before you uncomment this line of code.
    }
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks Sidd. Please see my longer response below (is that how you're supposed to answer someone on here?).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Sidd. With some error logging as you suggested, I've narrowed it down to the actual call to nlapiDeleteRecord. Here's my loop:

`for (var i = 0; searchresults != null && i < searchresults.length; i++)
{
    try
    {
        nlapiLogExecution("Debug", "About to delete record id " + searchresults[i].getId());

        nlapiDeleteRecord(searchresults[i].getRecordType(), searchresults[i].getId());
    }
    catch (err)
    {
        var errMessage = err;
        if(err instanceof nlobjError)
        {
            errMessage = errMessage + ' ' + err.getDetails() + ' ' + 'Failed to Delete ID : ' + id;
        }
        nlapiLogExecution('ERROR', 'Error', errMessage);
        return err
    }
}`

The ID it logs and the ID it shows in the error message are the same - so it logs "About to delete record id 1234" and then gives the error message:

Code: RCRD_DSNT_EXIST Details: That record does not exist. That record does not exist. Failed to Delete ID : 1234

But when I run my saved search, I find that it actually *has* deleted record 1234. Next time I run it, it will spit out the same messages - but about ID 1235. And then it will have deleted 1235. It's as if for some reason it tries to delete it twice, succeeding the first time and then failing the second time as it's already been deleted.

And I've checked the search repeatedly - it does NOT have multiple rows per quote. If I run the above with the delete line commented out, I get what I'd expect - a log entry for every ID in my search.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please share the Filters and Columns of your saved search. Looks like, the problem is with saved search.

Answer (score 0):

Next time try running your script in Script Debugger. You can easily track the cause of this error in Script Debugger.

Answer (score 0):

There could be another user event script executing on that delete event. The writer of the other script should have excluded delete, or only included his specific events, usually create or edit.

Check your server script instance to see which user event scripts are doing causing yours to fail.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).